# Better open source blockchain explorer for Quorum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, quorum, explorers

I was looking for open source blockchain explorers for Quorum blockchain other than https://github.com/blk-io/blk-explorer-free, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [CBX Quorum Explorer](https://github.com/Councilbox/cbx-quorum-explorer), which is free software.

Some characteristics:

- Real-time synchronization with little delay (~ 1 second).
- Rollback mechanism after abrupt crashes of the syncer module.
- Auto-reconnect on database downs.
- Auto-reconnect on source node downs.
- Recognition of accounts represented with and without checksum.
- Infinite scroll for blocks and transactions lists.
- Optional decoding of extraData field when using IBFT consensus (vanity, validators, seal and commitedSeals).

[image: CBX Quorum Explorer]

**Disclaimer**: I am the lead developer of the project.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 that should work that support Quorum specifically:
- Cakeshop: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/cakeshop/tree/quorum-ui
- Quorum-maker: https://github.com/synechron-finlabs/quorum-maker/

Answer (score 0):

Quorum now comes with a builtin UI "[cakeshop](https://github.com/ConsenSys/cakeshop/)"